# SSIS Data Flow overflowing on dates

Tags: date, ssis, foxpro, dataflow

I have a FoxPro data source, and the destination is SQL Server 2008.

On the FoxPro side, I have a column with the `Date` data type. That's a width of 8, min value is 0001-01-01 and max is 9999-12-31. On the SQL Server side, I have a `datetime`. Also a width of 8, min value is 1753-01-01 and max is 9999-12-31.

In my SSIS Data Flow task, I have an OLE DB Source component that reads in the FoxPro table. The columns are mapped as DT_DBDate in both External and Output Columns. The OLE DB Destination to the SQL Server table takes that columns and flows it to a DT_DBTIMESTAMP. I'm sure that DT_DBTIMESTAMP can handle these date ranges adequately, and reasonably sure about DT_DBDATE (but am having trouble finding it in MS documentation).

**The Problem**

When I execute the task, I've been having trouble with it failing and complaining of "Invalid date format" and then "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specific type" when it encounters values from around the early 1900s, to values over 2050. I'm not exactly sure where I've gone wrong.

**Bonus Question**

How can I handle overflows in my data flow task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to do a simple VFP query looking for the records that are beyond the range such as a VFP query of

```
select * from yourtable
   where YourDate < date( 1753, 1, 1 )
      or YourDate > date( 9999, 12, 31 )
```

look at those records for problems...
Additionally, look at other columns that may be causing your boundary issues

Comment: Yeah, I think I was looking at this the wrong way. It's more appropriate to handle according to business requirements, using queries, than anything else.

Comment: +1. This solved it for me for an import from MS Access. In Access the syntax is `select * from yourtable
where YourDate < #01-01-1753# 
OR YourDate > #01-01-9999#`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to decide what do you want to do with your data

If you want to load it as it is, you need to change field data type so it will be able to hold the data.

Or if you any wish to correct wrong data you would need to validate and transform it.

If you willing to spend some money please consider using Advanced ETL Processor.

It works with Text, XML, Excel, Access, DBF, Foxpro, ODBC, OLE DB, MS Sql Server, Oracle, MySql, PostgreSQL, Firebird, Interbase, SQLite, POP3, SMTP, File System, FTP, SSL and Unicode.